# Reconnect db в golang приложении

Tags: golang

Возник usecase.К примеру у нас есть приложение написанное на `golang`. Оно ходит в базу к примеру `mssql` c постоянным висячим коннектом к ней и в друг у нас произошло чп и база офнулась и опять поднялась. Вопрос переконектится ли коннект к базе самостоятельно при запросе пользователя или придется перезапускать самостоятельно приложение. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверил сам. Может кому будет интересно. Поднял в докере инстанс с `mysql` и начал долбится в него `connection.Ping()` в цикле. В итоге `golang` сам перезапускает коннект если связь была потеряна.